# Bitwise operation with 0x88

Tags: javascript

```
1 & 0x88 // output is 0
8 & 0x88 // output is 8
17 & 0x88 // output is 0
```

What is 0x88 and how does the bitwise operation works here?

Comment: Since you know that this is a bitwise operation, searching for explanations of that concept should be easy. So what exactly are you confused about that led to you ask here?

Comment: Convert both values to binary (left value is decimal, right value is hexadecimal, remove the `0x`). Then, compare each digit of both values. Whenever both are 1, the result will also have a 1 at this position, otherwise 0. Then, convert it back to hex or decimal to get your result. `0x88` is just the value 88 in hexadecimal. It is 136 in decimal and 10001000 in binary...

Answer (score 3):

`0x` says it is a hexadecimal representation.
0x88 = 136 in decimal = 10001000 in bits.

`0b` is the binary representation.
0b10001000 = 136 in decimal

With the bitwise `&` operator you check which bits on right side are also set in the left side. So you can check if a bitmask is set.

```
00000001 & 10001000 = 00000000 //    1 & 0x88
00001000 & 10001000 = 00001000 //    8 & 0x88
00010001 & 10001000 = 00000000 //   17 & 0x88
10001000 & 10001000 = 10001000 // 0x88 & 0x88
```

Practical example for storing multiple values in one byte with multiple bits. Here are four bits used as a bitmask.

```
const READ   = 1 << 0; // 0001
const WRITE  = 1 << 1; // 0010
const DELETE = 1 << 2; // 0100
const EXEC   = 1 << 3; // 1000

access    = READ | WRITE | EXEC; // 1011
canRead   = access & READ;       // 1 => true
canWrite  = access & WRITE;      // 1 => true
canDelete = access & DELETE;     // 0 => false
canExec   = access & EXEC;       // 1 => true
```

Comment: learned something new from your answer. Thanks for sharing your knowledge